# Does Windows XP SP3 include .NET Framework 2.0?

Tags: windows-xp, .net

Does Windows XP SP3 include .NET Framework 2.0 preinstalled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, .NET Framework 2.0 was not included with Windows XP SP3.

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx):

```
Windows XP Home and Professional SP3 includes the MSI-based
.NET Framework 1.1 + SP1 in the Additional Components folder
on the installation CD.  It is not an OS component on this OS.
```